# Broken grub rescue,due to corrupt Linux partition, will ubuntu reinstall fix it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, grubrescue

I have an Acer Aspire AO533 with dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Somehow my Ubuntu partition got corrupted and can no longer be accessed.As a result when I try to boot the machine I'm redirected to grub rescue, which I'm pretty sure is because the required grub modules can't be accessed any more. After spending lot of time googling the solution I was finally able to boot into my Windows installation using SuperGrub Disk (+1 to supergrub !). Now most of the solution I came across  pointed towards using a windows recovery disc, but I'm not able to create one as the netebook has no cd drive. So finally, my question is - will following procedure repair the broken grub and will allow me to boot safely into windows as well as ubuntu:

1)Delete the linux and linux swap patitions using windows disk management utility & unallocate the corresponding space.

2)Boot into ubuntu using a live usb.

3)Install ubutnu on the unallocated space treating it as a fresh installation.

Note: Please do not insist on booting through a windows recovery media, as I've already tried getting hold of one and have failed.
 I've also tried using testdisk and ddrescue in order to recover as much of my data from linux partition as possible but with no success, any suggestion in this regard will also be welcomed.

Update: I tried to delete the Linux partitions through Windows but windows crashed to blue screen of death, I don't know what to do now.Please help me guys !!!!

Comment: Only use the Something Else option to reinstall. Any auto reinstall options may erase all partitions. Do not delete partitions with Windows. You can just reuse partitions if you want the same sizes as they will be reformatted. You can also not reformat and try install and your data should not be overwritten. Did you try fsck to check file system?

Comment: Do you mean don't touch the corrupted partition and directly head towards installation ? And yes, I had already tried fsck which returns errors saying 'operation resulted in short read, could this be a zero length partition ?', so no luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have ubuntu root partition you can use Boot-repair. Link for how to do that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair